# Need to add FK constraint to table, while keeping existing data's relation to another table

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, database-design, relational-database

I currently have this schema, along with some data in both tables:

```
       animal table                   pet_accessories table
+---------------+---------+   +-----------------------+-----------+
|  animal_key   |   type  |   |  pet_accessories_key  |   animal  |
+---------------+---------+   +-----------------------+-----------+
|      1        |   Dog   |   |           1           |   Dog     |
|      2        |   Cat   |   |           2           |   Bird    |
|      3        |   Bird  |   |           3           |   Cat     |   
+---------------+---------+   |           4           |   Cat     | 
                              +-----------------------+-----------+
```

but need to add a relation between the tables with a FK constraint from pet_accessories to the animal table instead. Ultimately, this is what I'd need:

```
       animal table                   pet_accessories table
+---------------+---------+   +-----------------------+---------------+
|  animal_key   |   type  |   |  pet_accessories_key  |   animal_key  |
+---------------+---------+   +-----------------------+---------------+
|      1        |   Dog   |   |           1           |       1       |
|      2        |   Cat   |   |           2           |       3       |
|      3        |   Bird  |   |           3           |       2       |   
+---------------+---------+   |           4           |       2       | 
                              +-----------------------+---------------+
```

I have tried adding a new key column to my existing pet_accessories table, but having trouble with the logic that would set this animal_key correctly:

```
+-----------------------+-----------+--------------+
|  pet_accessories_key  |   animal  |  animal_key  |
+-----------------------+-----------+--------------+
|           1           |   Dog     |              |
|           2           |   Bird    |              |
|           3           |   Cat     |              | 
|           4           |   Cat     |              |
+-----------------------+-----------+--------------+
```

I understand that SQL is primarily a set-orientated language - it's generally a bad idea to use a loop in it. I have also read that I could probably use cursors instead, although I'm not too familiar with them.

Question is, what is the best way to loop thru the data in pet_accessories.animal and compare with animals.type so that I can finally set pet_accessories.animal_key = animal.animal_key for all existing pet_accessories records? In other words, how do I:

```
for each record in pet_accessories
  for each record in animal
    if pet_accessories.animal == animal.type
      then pet_accessories.animal_key = animal_animal_key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add the column:

```
alter table pet_accessories add animal_key integer;
```

Then, update the column:

```
update pa
    set animal_key = a.animal_key
    from pet_accessories pa join
         animals a
         on pa.animal = a.type;
```

Then, check to be sure everything is what you want.

Then, delete the old columns:

```
alter table pet_accessories drop column animal;
```

Then add the foreign key constraint:

```
alter table add constraint fk_animal_key
    foreign key (animal_key) references animal(animal_key);
```

Comment: What if I have 1 million records to update? How can I make this dynamic? That's why I was asking about how to iterate thru each record.

Comment: @LeonardoLopez . . . I don't understand your comment.  This assigns the `animal_key` to all records in the query, in one fell swoop.

Comment: Sorry about that question. You're absolutely right, Gordon. It's just that this sql statement looks so simple and elegant, I thought it was only updating the first record. Mind explaining in words how it iterates from one record to the next?

Comment: @LeonardoLopez . . . That is how SQL works -- on entire tables of data at the same time.